# i need to scale text size in UITableView with pinch to zoom in ios i am trying but cant able to do that

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)pinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"pinched");
    CGFloat lastScaleFactor=1;
    CGFloat factor =[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];
    if (factor > 1) {
        //zooming in
        _textView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor + (factor-1),lastScaleFactor + (factor -1));


    }
    else

    {
        _textView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor *factor, lastScaleFactor *factor +1);
    }
    if (sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (factor >1) {
            lastScaleFactor += (factor-1);

        }
        else
            lastScaleFactor *= factor;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

i want to do exactly like that
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYZmJyzkBgY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the linked video it is not the view transform that is changing, it is the font size (note how the text is reflowed). Simply apply your calculated scale to the textView's font size and that's it.

Secondly, your `lastScaleFactor` should probably be defined `static`, otherwise it doesn't make sense... Try something along the below lines (was not tested or even compiled, however should be straight forward to copy). The snippet below assumes you have plain text in the textView. In case you have attributed text, then you would have to change the place where a new font is assigned to the text view, and instead loop through all attributedText segments and modify each of the segments size accordingly; also you would have to keep temporary memo of the last fixed font size per each of the text segments, as it is done below for the whole text in the `currentFontSize` property

```
@interface ViewController ()
    @property CGFloat currentFontSize;
@end
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.currentFontSize = _textView.font.pointSize
}

- (IBAction)pinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"pinched");
    const CGFloat scaleCoeff = 0.5; //play with this one
    CGFloat factor =[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];

    if (sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.currentFontSize = _textView.font.pointSize;
    }
    else {
        _textView.font = [_textView.font fontWithSize:self.currentFontSize * factor * scaleCoeff];
    }
}
```